# What can we say if $A\twoheadrightarrow B$ and $A \rightarrowtail B$?

Tags: category-theory

In some category, suppose there are two objects $A$ and $B$ such that the arrow-class $\mathsf{Hom}(A,B)$ has a monic $A \rightarrowtail B$ and an epic $A\twoheadrightarrow B$. Can we say anything interesting about $A$ and $B$?

***Added:*** I'm also interested whether this implies anything interesting in special kinds of categories e.g abelian, closed monoidal, etc.

Comment: I doubt it, but +1 for asking a question I have sometimes wondered about.

Comment: This is similar in spirit to the Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein theorem, which says that in $\mathsf{Set}$, if $A \rightarrowtail B$ and $B \rightarrowtail A$, then $A \cong B$. The question of which categories this holds in has [come up](http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2007/10/30/theme-and-variations-schroeder-bernstein/) in the blogosphere [before](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1058/when-does-cantor-bernstein-hold).

Answer (score 2):

In general you can say nothing about $A$ and $B$.
Consider, for example, in category of unital rings, the inclusion $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Q$: it's monic and epic, but it isn't bijective.

Comment: It doesn't have to be in general. Are there perhaps interesting kinds of categories in which we *can* say something?

Comment: Yes, for example, in balanced categories, a morphism which is both monic and epic is an isomorphism. Examples are: abelian categories, regular categories, elementary toposes ecc...

Comment: Recall also that in a general category, an extremal epic monomorphism is an isomorphism and, dually an extremal monic epimorphism is an isomorphism.

Comment: Note I'm not requiring the monic and the epic to be the same arrow :)